# expo-asset useAssets hook returns undefined while there is cached image on the disk

Tags: react-native, caching, expo

When internet access is on, `useAssets` returns the localUri as expected. But after going offline, it returns undefined. Even the cached file still exists in the cache folder, it does not reference it. The code is below:

```
import React from "react";
import { useAssets } from "expo-asset";
import { Image, View } from "react-native";

export default function Avatar({ imageUrl}) {
  const [assets, error] = useAssets([imageUrl]);

  return (
    <View style={[styles.avatar, style]}>
      <Image
        source={{
          uri: assets[0].localUri
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

So I want to access downloaded and cached images offline with `useAssets` hook but it seems that `expo-assets` has not such feature, isn't it?

Comment: Any update how you solved this?

Answer (score -3):

You need to install the 'expo-asset' package.

expo install expo-asset

Comment: I believe that if OP didn't have that installed the code would fail on the import line. However, they report that there is a valid output with internet connection so I doubt that your answer solves the problem

Comment: I had the exact same issue and that is what solved it for me.

Comment: If its not installed, its obvious you cant use it